# How to render custom field taxonomy on Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-taxonomy

I've created some custom field in my taxonomy vocabulary called Categories:
- fotogallery (multiple files)
- incipit (plain text)
- ...

But I don't know how to render them.

I've tried [field_view_field](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_field/7) but it refers just to entity. I've tried render and drupal_render also.

Actually I'm accessing directly to $term->field_incipt['und'][0]['safe_value'] property, that I konw it's not recommended.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taxonomy terms in Drupal 7 *are* entities, and as such you can use `field_view_field()`to safely get the render array:

```
$view = field_view_field('taxonomy_term', $term, 'field_incipt'); 
print render($view);
```

Comment: I am trying to render description field using same method but it not working. Does it works only with custom field?

Comment: Not custom fields, just fields in general @Rajesh. The description is a property rather than field so there’s a distinction

Comment: Core uses the method here: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_build_content/7.x

Comment: Finally, find solution myself

    $term_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('taxonomy_term', $term);
    echo $term_wrapper->description->value();

Answer (score 0):

the field_view_field function works for me.
just note you need to send the term entity.
you can get one using entity_load
i.e. $term_entity = entity_load('taxonomy_term', array($tid));

Answer (score 0):

To properly get $term object, you should use [taxonomy_term_load()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_load/7) function and pass term id to it.